# Does salting and hashing protect from an attack on a single account?

Tags: security, encryption

If I salt and hash the password, is it safer than just hashing the password if a potential attacker has the salt string and is attacking only one account - let's say there are no other accounts in the DB?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Brute-forcing and dictionary attacks would take the same amount of time, but having a salt would still prevent rainbow-table attacks.

So yes, even if your application is expected to have one user, I would still recommend a salt.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, hashing passwords without salt is less safe.

Salt prevents the use of pre-computed reverse lookup tables.

Just because there is only one account in *your* database doesn't mean an attacker can't use a pre-computed table he generated to attack other systems. There are also tables available online for poorly designed systems like the old Windows LAN Manager.

Using salt is easy and safe. What reason would you have to skip it?

Comment: So an attacker would have to create a reverse lookup table based on that salt and the algorithm for encryption?

Comment: @A-OK: That is equivalent to brute-forcing the password.  The point of reverse lookup tables is that they are *pre* -computed.

Comment: @A-OK - I thought the premise of the question is that there is no salt, so I'm not sure what you mean by creating a "table based on that salt." However, yes, a lookup table is dedicated to a particular hashing algorithm and number of iterations.

Answer (score 1):

Salting helps prevent attackers from using brute force or rainbow tables to find hashed common passwords.

if the attackers knows the salt you used, you loose all protection from the brute force but will still have protection from the rainbow tables. Well unless the rainbow table was generated with your salt.

Best security is to use custom salt for each hashed password. Protects against rainbow tables and makes it a bit more annoying for brute force attacks.

Comment: Salt doesn't do anything for brute-force attacks. That's handled by "key strengthening" (adding computational expense, typically by iterating the hash algorithm a few thousand times).

Comment: In the most academic definition of what a brute-force attack is, I will agree salting doesn't help. However in the real world, every brute force hash cracking tool I've seen uses a dictionary of some type as a seeder to optimize common password search patterns. In cases like that salting can help to prevent these tools from working.